# php header issues in iis7

Tags: php, iis, header

I have get the issues for php header in iis7. if any page use 'php header' function get the internal server error page. Please help me for this issues.

Regards

Comment: please paste your error information exact what u r getting

Comment: Thanks for reply i am not getting any specific error. When get the 500 internal server error page only.

Answer (score -1):

@chakku

it means u r in cycle of header problem..simple called deadlocks..

#### eg:

> on page x u write header("location:y") and
> on page y u write header("location:z") and
> on page z u  write header("location:x")

so please check all the `header()`

Comment: [Reference] (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/http-error-500-internal-server-for-php-pages-and-solution.html)

Comment: diEcho thanks for reply i will check it. let you know the result

Comment: While this could be a reason, it is not the only one.